# What is the standard way to use Kotlin+Sockets+Coroutines?

Tags: sockets, kotlin, coroutine

Is it currently possible to coroutines in Kotlin for networking?

I could find examples with threads but not with coroutines.

Comment: Please specify your question. Coroutines are an abstraction for asynchronous operations, while network(ing) is a communication (behavior) - I have troubles to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `Dispatchers.IO` dispatcher to work with sockets from coroutines like you do it from threads - sockets are blocking I/O, so each sockets takes a whole thread, and this dispatcher can launch a LOT of threads.

Also there are some non-blocking I/O libraries for Java, and you may find adapters from them to Kotlin Coroutines API (for example, you may use [this proxy between Netty and Coroutines](https://github.com/oleksiyp/netty-coroutines)).